# Passing Code Generation Properties to TDS T4 templates

Tags: tds, code-generation

I want to pass some additional parameters to my T4 code generation templates in my TDS projects. In the TDS Projects Code Generation properties tab, there is a field for passing additional code generation properties, but I can't get this to work. I thought it would work like this:

Passing the parameters like this:

[image: TDS Project Code Generation Properties tab]

and then pick up the value in the T4 template like this:

```
<#@ parameter name="MyProperty" type="System.String" #>
<#
   if (MyProperty == ...) 
      ...
#>
```

But the above doesn't work. The value of `MyProperty` is always empty when running the T4 generation. What am I doing wrong? Have I perhaps completely misunderstood this feature?

(I'm using TDS 6.0.0.18, i.e. latest version when writing this)

Comment: Not sure how to fix your problem, but have you looked in to [Leprechaun](https://github.com/blipson89/Leprechaun) for CodeGen? Its so much better than T4!

Comment: Thanks, but switching to Leprechaun would be a major change in this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to get a property [like it is passed into a session variable.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/t4-parameter-directive?view=vs-2019)
But TDS passes Additional Code Generation Properties into `SitecoreItem` model. That is why you need to use a different approach to get values.

You are able to get your properties from `SitecoreItem` type, `AdditionalProperties` field ynside your Base Project Transform File (usually, GlassItemVX.tt):

e.g.

```
<#@ parameter name="Model" type="HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.CodeGeneration.Models.SitecoreItem" #>
string myProperty = Model.AdditionalProperties["MyProperty"];
Write(myProperty);#>
```

Will generate this outcome:

```
MyValue
```